# How to eliminate Permission error in django xlrd

Tags: python, django, xlrd

I try creating model fields by importing an excel with the details but get the permission errors. What could be the problem...

The view.

```
def UploadTeacherView(request):
    message=''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewTeachersForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            excel_file = request.FILES['file']
            try:
                import os
                import tempfile
                import xlrd
                fd, tmp = tempfile.mkstemp() # create two temporary file
                with os.open(fd, 'wb') as out: # create new file objects
                    out.write(excel_file.read())
                book = xlrd.open_workbook(tmp)
                print(book)
                sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
                obj=TeacherData(
                    code = sheet.cell_value(rowx=1, colx=1),
                    first_name = sheet.cell_value(rowx=2, colx=1),
                    last_name = sheet.cell_value(rowx=3, colx=1),
                    email = sheet.cell_value(rowx=4, colx=1),
                    phone = sheet.cell_value(rowx=5, colx=1),

                )
                obj.save()
            finally:
                os.remove(tmp)
        else:
            message='Invalid Entries'
    else:
        form = NewTeachersForm()
    return render(request,'new_teacher.html', {'form':form,'message':message})
```

Below is the error I get upon uploading a file.

```
PermissionError at /teachers/upload
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\FRGULI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpm87yli8l'
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\Links_Online_Results\teachers\views.py", line 41, in UploadTeacherView
with os.open(fd, 'wb') as out: # create new file objects
TypeError: open: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not int

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\Links_Online_Results\teachers\views.py", line 55, in UploadTeacherView
    os.unlink(tmp)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\FRGULI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpkdyl14y2'
```

Comment: Your Excel file is already opened by another process (Excel). Or, there is a remaining lock file in the directory.

Comment: How do I get rid of this????? And is the code well formatted??? @Laurent LAPORTE

Comment: Close the Excel app and run the code again.

Comment: No excel is opened anywhere...

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is happening.  Please update the question to include the full error message traceback.

Comment: Traceback added @John Gordon.

Comment: Are you sure this is the real code?  The error traceback has `os.unlink(tmp)`, but the posted code has `os.remove(tmp)`...

Comment: @John Gordon. I figured out where my mistake was an corrected.